# Excel VBA to insert columns and split cell contents

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet  which contains following content:

[image]

I have worked on VBA code which does following:-

1. Find the column having Header **ABC**
2. Insert two new columns adjacent to **ABC** with name of **AAA** and **BBB**
3. Then split the **ABC** cell content into respective cells of **AAA** and **BBB**; note (**ABC** column may have one one line in some cases )
4. Follow step (3) till end of column **ABC** content.

End result should look like this:

[image]

I have written following code :-

```
Sub Num()
Dim rngDHeader As Range
Dim rngHeaders As Range
Set rngHeaders = Range("1:1") 'Looks in entire first row; adjust as needed.
Set rngDHeader = rngHeaders.Find("ABC")

Sub sbInsertingColumns()
'Inserting a Column at Column B
rngDHeader.EntireColumn.Insert
'Inserting 2 Columns from C
rngDHeader.EntireColumn.Insert
 Dim rngDHeader As Range
   Dim sText As String
   Dim aText As Variant 'array
   Dim i As Long        'number of array elements

   Set rngDHeader = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2")

   Do Until rng = ""

      'split the text on carriage return character chr(10)
      aText = Split(rngDHeader.Value, Chr(10))

      'get the number of array elements
      i = UBound(aText)

      'build the output text string
      sText = aText(i - 2) & Chr(10) _
              & aText(i - 1) & Chr(10) _
              & aText(i)

      'output
      rngDHeader.Offset(, 1) = sText

      Set rngDHeader = rngDHeader.Offset(1, 0)
   Loop

   Set rngDHeader = Nothing

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: First help: Sub inside Sub is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbered as per your question:

1.Find the Column having Header ABC

```
Dim colNum as Integer
colNum = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find(what:="ABC", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
```

2.Insert Two new Column Adjacent to ABC with Name of AAA and BBB

```
' Done twice to insert 2 new cols
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert    
ActiveSheet.Columns(colNum + 1).Insert

' New col headings
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 1).Value = "AAA"
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colNum + 2).Value = "BBB"
```

3.Then Split the ABC cell content into respective AAA and BBB; note (ABC column may have one one line in some cases )

**and**

4.Follow the process till end of column ABC content.

```
' Define the range to iterate over as the used range of the found column
Dim colRange as Range 
With ActiveSheet
    Set colRange = .Range(.Cells(2, colNum), .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, colNum))
End With

Dim splitStr() as String

Dim vcell as Range
For Each vcell in colRange

    ' Create an array by splitting on the line break
    splitStr = Split(vcell.value, Chr(10))    

    ' Assign first new column as first array value.
    ActiveSheet.Cells(vcell.row, colNum + 1).Value = splitStr(0)

    ' Assign second new column as second array value. 
    ' First test if there *is* a second array value
    If UBound(splitStr) > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(vcell.row, colNum + 2).Value = splitStr(1)        
    End If  

Next vcell
```

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` isn't the best way to handle the problem that the source cell from `ABC` row doesn't contain `Chr(1)` AKA `vbLf` (meaning `splitStr(1)` will throw an error). That is why in my answer, I've just taken the left and right hand sides of the first vbLf found in the cell value.

Comment: Hi @RobinMackenzie, thanks for your feedback, I'm sure you intended it to sound more constructive than it does... I was trying to avoid introducing more concepts than I needed to, I've now used `UBound` to avoid the error in a simple fix... both work exactly the same though :)

Comment: no offence meant with the feedback - your answer is good. I just thought that masking the error wasn't the best way to handle it. Appreciate your point about not introducing more concepts than necessary - just in this one particular case I felt it was worth a mention. FWIW I have also had (much more) negative feedback by trying to write answers that don't throw too much in so they are more accessible to the OP and I agree it is a bit frustrating to get other people piling on that.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie no worries, all fixed now with whats probably a more elegant solution anyway :)

Comment: Excellent work and works as it supposed to!! I just have one query can we limit this macro to one time use only??

Comment: You could add an `If` statement to check if the column heading `BBB` already exists before the split happens? Be aware that the `Find` function will throw an error if you use it and `BBB` doesn't exist...